# Linearized Waldhausen $K$-Theory

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology

In Waldhausen's foundational $A(X)$ paper (in Springer LNM 1126) there are some brief remarks on p. 400 about how to define the "linearized" $K$-theory of a space $X$ using abelian group objects in the category of spaces over $X$ rather than abelian group objects in the category of $G$-spaces.

I need to understand these remarks, and would be happy to hear from anybody who already understands them.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make some guesses, although I worry I'll only say some formal things you already know (or that are wrong).

One description of the Waldhausen K-theory of a pointed connected space $X$ is that it is the algebraic K-theory of the group algebra $\mathbb{S}[\Omega X]$ of its loop space over the sphere spectrum. Module spectra over $\mathbb{S}[\Omega X]$ have the following equivalent descriptions:

- Representations of $\Omega X$ on spectra.
- Families of spectra over $X$ (by a kind of Koszul duality).

What Waldhausen seems to mean by "linearization" is passing from the sphere spectrum to $\mathbb{Z}$, by which I mean $\mathbb{Z}$ the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum. Now we want to look at the algebraic K-theory of the group algebra $\mathbb{Z}[\Omega X]$. A more familiar avatar of this, passing through stable Dold-Kan, is chains $C_{\bullet}(\Omega X)$. Module spectra over this group algebra have the following equivalent descriptions:

- Representations of $\Omega X$ on $\mathbb{Z}$-module spectra.
- Representations of $\Omega X$ on chain complexes over $\mathbb{Z}$ (by stable Dold-Kan).
- Under a connectivity hypothesis, representations of $\Omega X$ on simplicial abelian groups (by ordinary Dold-Kan).
- Under a connectivity hypothesis, representations of $\Omega X$ on topological abelian groups (by a suitably monoidal version of the equivalence between simplicial sets and topological spaces).
- Under a connectivity hypothesis, families of topological abelian groups over $X$, or abelian groups in families of spaces over $X$ (by Koszul duality again).

Comment: That's the formal picture, but I wanted to understand a certain part of it carefully, and I was hoping to do so by using technical details hinted at in that reference. I think I've sort of got it now. There is a functor that takes an abelian group with $\Omega X$-action and makes a 'family of abelian groups over $X$'. This has a left adjoint which I wish I had a better concrete grasp of. Put appropriate notions of weak equivalence and cell object on these two categories, and then show that the left adjoint induces an equivalence of $K$-theory.